# Application SQL Server Timeout because of metadatalock?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, locking

I get the following generic Timeout expired error in my .NET Application when I run a program which does an update to the database.

[image: Timeout]

In SQL Server Activity Monitor, when this error appears, it shows there is a lock on the database shown in the next image.

[image: metadatalock]

Any idea what could be going on here? I think it is permissions related because when I log on with my Windows Administrator account, it runs through fine and doesn't error out. Also, I don't think it is really a time out issue as SQL Server is set to time out after 10 minutes and so are the Sql Commands I create in my code.

Any ideas, what permissions I would need to change to stop this from happening for my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by logging in as an Administrator, so permissions related.